# Format DateTime Diff to prevent showing 0 years 0 months in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to find the difference between today's date and a specific date from the database.
I used DateTime Diff to get the result and its given me the correct answer in **(years months and days)** format. The only problem is if the diff is less then a year it show 0 years which is not desired. Same for months and Days.
Is it possible to check if any of the 3 values is 0 or is their any other method to accomplish this?

Here's the code i am using-

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($asset[$a]['PDate']);
$datetime2 = new DateTime("now");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%y years %m months and %d days');
```

$datetime1 is from database whereas $datetime2 shows today's date. If $datetime1 is something like 12/9/2015 & %datetime2 is 12/3/2015 the output I get is  **0 years 0 months and 6 days** whereas I want it to display only **6 days**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So check with the format like this:

```
if($datetime1->format('%y') != 0)
    echo $datetime1->format('%y years %m months and ');
if($datetime1->format('%y') == 0 && $datetime1->format('%m') != 0)
    echo $datetime1->format('%m months and ');
echo $datetime1->format('%d days');
```

or (restructured):

```
if($datetime1->format('%y') != 0) {
    echo $datetime1->format('%y years %m months and ');
} else {
    if($datetime1->format('%m') != 0)
        echo $datetime1->format('%m months and ');
}
echo $datetime1->format('%d days');
```

This will output:

2 years 2 months and 2 days
2 months and 2 days (if 0 years) 
2 days (if 0 years and 0 months)
2 years 0 months and 2 days (if 0 months)

if month should not be printed if its value is 0 (irrespective of year)

```
$flag = false;
if($datetime1->format('%y') != 0) {
    echo $datetime1->format('%y years ');
    $flag= true;
}
if($datetime1->format('%m') != 0) {
    echo $datetime1->format('%m months ');
    $flag= true;
}
if($datetime1->format('%d') != 0) {
    echo $flag?"and ":"";
    echo $datetime1->format('%d days');
}
```

This will output:

2 years 2 months and 2 days
2 months and 2 days (if 0 years) 
2 days (if 0 years and 0 months)
2 years and 2 days (if 0 months)

Comment: Yeah! I had to restructure anyways to get rid of the 0 months

Comment: I thought you need to print month if there is year. See the updated answer now. Now month won't be printed when it's value is 0.

Comment: No, I just wanted to print the non-zero values. Thanx a lot for your help!!

Comment: Remember to use `$intervall->format()` not `$datetime1->format()`

Answer (score 0):

explode the values of time diffrent and check the day format is 0 or not as given below

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($asset[$a]['PDate']);
$datetime2 = new DateTime("now");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$different= $interval->format('%y years %m months and %d days');

//eg :$different= '1 years 1 months and 7 days';
$a=explode(' ',$different);
print_r($a);
if($a[0]>0){
$y=$a[0]."years  ";
}else{$y="";}
if($a[2]>0){
$m=$a[2]."months  ";
}else{$m="";}
if($a[5]>0){
$d=$a[5]."days   ";
}
echo $y,$m,$d;
```

Comment: @Shashank Surwase : is this answer doesn't satisfies your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wanted to come up with something more simple than the following (which is what brought me here in the first place) but I think this is an improvement over the accepted answer. It's technically a tad bit shorter too, but more importantly it accommodates the edge case of 0 days. (where in the accepted answer would print `y years m months` omitting the word "and"):

```php
<?php 

$datetime1 = new DateTime($asset[$a]['PDate']);
$datetime2 = new DateTime;
$interval = array_filter((array) $datetime1->diff($datetime2));

$spec = ['y' => 'years', 'm' => 'months', 'd' => 'days'];
foreach ($spec as $key => $unit) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $interval)) {
        $out[] = "{$interval[$key]} $unit";
    }
}

if ((count($out)) > 1) {
    $last = array_pop($out);
    $out[] = "and $last";
}

echo implode(' ', $out);
```

This works because the `DateInterval` object (resulting from the call to `DateTime::diff()`) contains public properties which map to associative keys when casted to an array. `array_filter` removes values equal to zero by default.

There are other improvements/considerations; for example, to follow plural rules, you can added a conditional in the `forloop`:

```php
$spec = ['y' => 'year', 'm' => 'month', 'd' => 'day'];
foreach ($spec as $key => $unit) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $interval)) {
        $value = $interval[$key];
        if ($value > 1) {
            $unit .= 's';
        }
        $out[] = "$value $unit";
    }
}
```

Or perhaps you want to join by commas except for the last element, in which case the last bit of code would be rewritten:

```php
$last = array_pop($out);
if ((count($out)) > 0) {
    $last = implode(', ', $out) . " and $last";
}

echo $last;
```

You can see it in action as a function here: https://3v4l.org/vYsE7
or if you prefer a condensed problem specific variation: https://3v4l.org/9FBP5

The function is pretty modular but defaults to almost exactly what the OP wanted except for the final *" and "* word which is passed in as an option.